# CakePHP add a new mysql table and How to configure

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm newbie in CakePHP and developing a pre-made app. I've created a mysql table and wondering how to use it inside the Controller.

This is the Controller:

```
class ManagersController extends AppController
{
     //--- Variables
    var $uses = array('User', 'Onlinetran', 'Pincode', 'Product', 'Setting');
    var $components = array('Jtime', 'Email', 'Session', 'Auth');
    var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session', 'Javascript', 'Paginator', 'Xml', 'Qoute');
    var $paginate = array('limit' => 35);
    var $setting;
    var $statsdata = array();
    var $statsSales;
    var $faildTrans;
    var $interval = 14;
    var $currentDay;
    var $aggregateEarning;

    // --- Functions
}
```

I've added a new table "discount" How to use it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a [model](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models.html) called `Discount` for it.

Add it to `$uses`

```
public $uses = array('User', 'Onlinetran', 'Pincode', 'Product', 'Setting', 'Discount');
```

Use it like:

```
$this->Discount->...
```

If the table is called `discount`, please use

```
public $useTable = 'discount'
```

in the model, because Cake will look for a table called `discounts`, by default.

If the table is called `discounts`, you don't need to create a model for it, unless you need custom functions.

Set debugging mode to 2, so you can see errors on your development machine, and clear cache

Comment: I've created model as well : <?php
class Discount extends AppModel
{ var $name = 'discount';
}
?> but immediately after putting "Discount" in $uses whole the /managers get not found error: "Not Found

Error: The requested address '/managers' was not found on this server."

Comment: Yes it works you are a genius :D Thanks i got the problem where it is. thank you extremely

Comment: If the table was called `discounts`, it wouldn't have needed a model for it. If you have $use = array('Discount'); Cake will look for a model called Discount. If you don't have one, it will still look for a mysql table called discounts and it is able to perform normal model operations, like `find`, on them. You can read more here book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models.html.

Comment: Very helpful cornel :)